# Reject future dates in jsp

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date of birth field in my html form as follows:

```
Date of Birth 
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" onchange="ageCalculation()">
```

In agecalculation function i want to reject future dates and also age should not be greater than 8 years.The javascript is:

```
function ageCalculation(){

       var currentDate = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dob").value);
    var difference = currentDate - birthDate;

    var differenceInYears = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
    if(birthDate.after(currentDate)|| differenceInYears>8)
        {
         window.alert("Age should be less than 8 years");
        }
    else{
    document.getElementById("age").value = differenceInYears ;}

       }
```

However I am getting Uncaught TypeError: birthDate.after is not a function

At the beginning of my htnl form i have written

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
```

Comment: I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com): `moment(birthDate) < moment().minus(8, 'years')`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of after just use a comparision with "<". Additionally I have modified your if-clause.

```js
function ageCalculation(){

  var currentDate = new Date();
  var val = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var birthDate = new Date(val);
  var difference = currentDate - birthDate;
  
  var differenceInYears = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
  if(birthDate > currentDate) {
    window.alert("You cannot be born in the future");
  } else if( differenceInYears>8) {
    window.alert("Age should be less than 8 years");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("age").value = differenceInYears ;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" onchange="ageCalculation()"> 
<input id="age"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, firstly that not all browsers in use support input type date, so you must validate the value that is returned. You should also provide the format for the date to be entered (yyyy-mm-dd in this case). Where browsers support date inputs, the value returned will be an ISO 8601 format date like 2016-08-30.

A further issue is that if you use the Date constructor to parse the string (or use Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing), it will be treated as UTC. Time zone effects may then create a Date different date. This will only affect dates for the time zone overlap, but it will be annoying for certain times on that date.

So you need to validate that the values are actual date values and parse the string as local. You can then do the age calculation very simply by adding 8 years to the provided birth date and seeing if it's after today. If it is, the person is not yet 8. Otherwise, they are.

```js
/* Check if birth date is more than 8 years
** ago. Result is written to form.result
** @param {DOMElement} el - form control
*/ 
function checkAge(el) {
  var dateString = el.form.birthDate.value;
  var d = parseISOLocal(dateString);
  var result;

  // Check date was valid
  if (isNaN(d)) {
    result = 'Invalid date';

  // Add 8 years to provided date and check if on or before today
  } else {
    d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 8);
    if (d <= new Date()) {
      result = '8 years or older';
    } else {
      result = 'Under 8 years old';
    }
  }
  el.form.result.value = result;
}

/* Parse ISO 8601 format date as local
** @param {string} s - date string in format yyyy-mm-dd
** @returns {Date} from parsing string as a
** local date. If date has invalid values,
** an invalid Date is returned
*/
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  Enter birthday (yyyy-mm-dd)<input type="date" name="birthDate" value="2008-08-31"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="checkAge(this)" value="Check 8 or over">
  <input type="text" readonly name="result">
</form>
```